# setcookie is not working after uploaded to live server

Tags: php, server, cpanel, setcookie

I have used setcookie in php to check users visiting my site. The thing is when i test it in my local server it works, the cookie gets set but when i upload the page in cpanel the cookie doesn't get set.
Below is a synopsis of my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
//set the cookie time to desired value;
setcookie("user", "abc", time()+3600);
//some other codes

if(!isset($_COOKIE["user"]))
{
//some other codes
}
?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The `setcookie()` function will add some HTTP headers to your response so that your browser stores a cookie named "user". As you also started a session, it will also ask your browser to store another cookie named "PHPSESSID". The `$_COOKIE` array is empty at the first page load because your browser didn't have them before the first visit. If you go in your browser inspector you should find both of them. Now if you reload the page, the browser will send these cookies in the request and then they will show up in `var_export($_COOKIE)`. Check the HTTP headers to see if they are correct.

Comment: Now, I've got a question: for which reason you need to set another cookie "user"? Why not storing it in the PHP session array `$_SESSION`? It might be interesting to explain what you are trying to do because we might could help you find the best solution to your problem.

Comment: it worked on my local system but im getting problem on server the cookie isn't set any sol!

Comment: i set the cookie for user to be able to login even if after browser windows closed like all social media site does

Comment: Then check the HTTP response and see if you have the `Set-Cookie: user=abc; expires=Mon, 04-Oct-2021 07:53:39 GMT; Max-Age=3600` header. If it's missing then ok, your server has a specific config or something disabled.

Comment: the only problem i got is unable to store the cookie on my browser

Comment: Did my answer below help you do what you where wanting to do?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answers to my questions in the comments, you probably just need to modify the cookie lifetime of your session and not create another "user" cookie.

```php
// TTL (Time To Live) of the cookie stored in the browser.
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 432000); // 5 days

// On the server side, the garbage collector should delete
// old sessions too, after the same TTL.
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 432000); // 5 days

// Fire the garbage collector only every 100 requests.
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
```

Do that at the beginning of your code, typically in a `config.php` file included at the bootstrap of your app.

You can see more [in the PHP session configuration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php).

There's a little problem regarding the lifetime: the cookie will expire after the lifetime set, but since the cookie was created, so at the moment your session was initiated the first time at login.

Usually, you want the cookie lifetime to start at the last user's action. You can do that by updating the cookie so that PHP re-sends the Cookie HTTP header to overwrite it. I also added a bunch of other security settings one should do on PHP sessions. Everything is commented in the running example below:

```php
<?php

/**
 * Testing PHP cookie settings and improve security.
 */

// The cookie lifetime in seconds.
define('COOKIE_LIFETIME', 10);

// Simulate user's data from the database.
$user_mail = 'james.bond@gmail.com';
// A salt per user is good. It avoids an attacker to be able
// to calculate the session cookie name himself if he discovers that
// it is just done by hashing the user's e-mail.
$user_salt = 'nbVzr432';

// Detect if we are over HTTPS or not. Needs improvement if behind a SSL reverse-proxy.
// It's just used for the cookie secure option to make this POC work everywhere.
$is_https = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']);

// On the PHP server side, the garbage collector should delete
// old sessions after the same lifetime value.
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', COOKIE_LIFETIME);

// Fire the garbage collector only every 100 requests to save CPU.
// On some OS this is done by a cron job so it could be commented.
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);

// Improve some session settings:
ini_set('session.use_cookies ', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies  ', 1);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode ', 1);

// This POC will just print some plain text.
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

// Change the session cookie name so that an attacker cannot find it.
$session_cookie_name = 'SESS_' . sha1($user_mail . $user_salt);
// Store all the session cookie options in an array.
$session_cookie_options = [
    // Set the cookie lifetime (the browser sets an expire to delete it automatically).
    'lifetime' => COOKIE_LIFETIME,
    // The cookie path defines under which relative URL the cookie should be sent.
    // If your app is running under https://your-site.com/shop/ then the cookie path
    // should be set to /shop/ instead of the default / as there's no reason to send
    // your shop's session cookie to another app running at https://your-site.com/forum/.
    'path' => '/',
    // Cookie domain. Use null to let PHP handle that. But if you want a session
    // cookie accross multiple sub-domains such as forum.your-site.com and shop.your-site.com
    // then you should set the domain to ".your-site.com".
    'domain' => null,
    // If we are in HTTPS then don't let cookies be sent over HTTP.
    // Here I used $is_https to make it run everywhere but if you have
    // HTTPS on your domain then replace it by 1 to lock it!
    'secure' => $is_https ? 1 : 0, // IMPORTANT: Replace by 1 if you have both HTTP and HTTPS enabled.
    // Don't let JavaScript access the session cookie.
    'httponly' => 1,
    // If another site has a link pointing to your website then don't send
    // the session cookie (POST or GET). This mitigates somes kind of attacks.
    'samesite' => 'Strict',
];

// Apply all the session cookie settings without ini_set() for maximum portability:
session_name($session_cookie_name);
session_set_cookie_params($session_cookie_options); // Since PHP 7.3 only
session_start();

// If the session cookie has been sent by the browser then it might have an expiration
// date to early (because it is set only once at the creation of the session).
// Instead we would like it to expire with our lifetime since the last user's
// action. To do that we have to use setcookie() to resend the cookie in order
// to update/overwrite it to have a new expiration date in the browser.
if (isset($_COOKIE[$session_cookie_name]) && $_COOKIE[$session_cookie_name] == session_id()) {
    $cookie_options = $session_cookie_options;
    unset($cookie_options['lifetime']); // This one is replaced by expires below.
    $cookie_options['expires'] = time() + COOKIE_LIFETIME;
    setcookie($session_cookie_name, session_id(), $cookie_options);
}

// Now that HTTP headers have been set, we are allowed to start printing output.

// If the user is already logged and his caddie is empty then fill it with some
// random stuff. It will stay saved until the session expires.
if (isset($_SESSION['session_creation_date']) && !isset($_SESSION['shop_caddie'])) {
    $_SESSION['shop_caddie'] = [
        'T-shirt' => [
            'quantity' => rand(1, 3),
            'color' => 'red',
        ],
        'Beer' => [
            'quantity' => (['2dl', '3dl', '5dl'])[rand(0, 2)],
        ]
    ];
}

// If the session is empty, let's init it with the creation date for the showcase.
if (empty($_SESSION)) {
    $_SESSION['session_creation_date'] = date('r');
}

print 'Recieved cookies from the browser = ' . var_export($_COOKIE, true) . "\n\n";
print 'Session data = ' . var_export($_SESSION, true) . "\n\n";
```